# Flutter Web won't launch link externally

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

I'm currently working on a flutter Webapp and I'm having trouble opening links to external websites. It seems very trivial but can't seem to figure out why the link is opening under the hosting domain e.g. [www.mydomain.com/www.google.com](http://www.mydomain.com/www.google.com)

I tried two methods:

dart:html with - html.window.open("www.google.com", "_blank") or html.window.location.assign("www.google.com")

URL_Launch Plugin - await launch("www.google.com)

I tried running them in a blank new project but the same results.

Any input on what I'm missing would be greatly appreciated - I tried other Stack threads and googling the issue but it just seems like this should just work.

Thanks in advance

Comment: you want to open url when tou click on section?

Answer (score 0):

You need to put in link https://

```
URL_Launch Plugin - await launch("https://www.google.com)
```

or

```
html.window.open("https://www.google.com", "_blank")
```